# Swift: prepare for segue listening to all segues on ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

heyho,
I am trying to fire the prepare Event for 1 Segue only. Where is the mistake?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let post = myCollection[indexPath!.row].id
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailVC

        controller?.thisPost = post
    }
}
```

Of course if I wouldn't do the if clause, it would fire on any segue out of the VC - oddly does anyway?

Comment: What did you name all of your segues?

Comment: they are all named differently - 100% positive that name is correct and no doubles

although "show Detail", does not point to a manual segue from VC to VC, it points to a cell-segue from a UITableViewCell to the DetailVC

Comment: How are you triggering the other segues that also end up with "showDetail" as the identifier?

Comment: I am going to hide under a rock now... I obviously dragged a Segue into Storyboard and forgot to name it... guess what happens if my func wants to check if it is the one it is looking for...

Thanks for putting my nose on "names"! :)